# How to disable ripple effect on any Jetpack Compose view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

In [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), how to remove (or change the shape of) the ripple effect when clicking on an Item ?

This is an example with [`NavigationBar`](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/implementation/android) from [Material Design 3](https://m3.material.io/)

```
var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")

NavigationBar {
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationBarItem(
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
            label = { Text(item) },
            selected = selectedItem == index,
            onClick = { selectedItem = index }
        )
    }
}
```

Trying to add a `Modifier` with

```
modifier = Modifier.clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource,indication = null){}
```

both on the `NavigationBar` and on the `NavigationBarItem`, does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it by providing [`LocalRippleTheme`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ripple/package-summary#LocalRippleTheme()). All views inside `CompositionLocalProvider` `content` will have no ripple.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalRippleTheme provides ClearRippleTheme
) {
    NavigationBar {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(item) },
                selected = selectedItem == index,
                onClick = { selectedItem = index }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

`ClearRippleTheme`:

```
object ClearRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Transparent

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha() = RippleAlpha(
        draggedAlpha = 0.0f,
        focusedAlpha = 0.0f,
        hoveredAlpha = 0.0f,
        pressedAlpha = 0.0f,
    )
}
```