# How we can remove ripple effect from toggle button in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-togglebutton

I have the toggle button in android jetpack compose, I want to remove ripple effect, when I click the toggle buttons. I try to find a solution on internet, but I did not find clear solution for this kind of example. Is there any idea?

```
   @Composable
 fun MainScreen() {

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),


  ) {
  
        var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

        MainRow(
            name = "name1",
            change = selected, onCheckedChange = {
                selected = it

            }))}}}
        
@Composable
fun MainRow(
name: String,
change:Boolean,
onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit

 ) {

 Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),

    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

) {

    Text(
        text = name,
       
    )

        Switch(
            modifier = Modifier
                .scale(1f),
            checked = change,
          
            onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange,
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                checkedThumbColor = Color.Red,
                uncheckedThumbColor = Color.Green,
                checkedTrackColor = Color.Yellow,
                uncheckedTrackColor = Color.Blue
            ))}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable ripple effect on any Jetpack Compose view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69783654/how-to-disable-ripple-effect-on-any-jetpack-compose-view)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, I try it, but not help me before

Comment: could you show how have you tried? Here's [my sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/de36de89ce3cecbc77ba3236e4f0b028) and it works as expected.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, it is good example also, but I did not success to apply to this project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary?hl=bg#:%7E:text=the%20MutableInteractionSource%20representing%20the%20stream%20of%20Interactions%20for%20this%20Switch.%20You%20can%20create%20and%20pass%20in%20your%20own%20remembered%20MutableInteractionSource%20if%20you%20want%20to%20observe%20Interactions%20and%20customize%20the%20appearance%20/%20behavior%20of%20this%20Switch%20in%20different%20Interactions.):

> interactionSource - the MutableInteractionSource representing the stream of Interactions for this Switch. You can create and pass in your own remembered MutableInteractionSource if you want to observe Interactions and customize the appearance / behavior of this Switch in different Interactions.

So you can write your own `MutableInteractionSource` like this:

```
class DisabledInteractionSource : MutableInteractionSource {

    override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()

    override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}

    override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true

}
```

And use it like this:

```
    Switch(
        modifier = Modifier
            .scale(1f),
        checked = change,
        interactionSource = remember { DisabledInteractionSource() },
        onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange,
        colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
            checkedThumbColor = Color.Red,
            uncheckedThumbColor = Color.Green,
            checkedTrackColor = Color.Yellow,
            uncheckedTrackColor = Color.Blue
        )
    )
```